# Can I create a ListView that will populate the actual table names in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm relatively new to Android and SQLite database use, but I appreciate any and all feedback.

I'm trying to create a listview that will populate the actual table names in an activity from an existing sqlite database that I will package with the application.  The idea would be to have the user click on a table name, which in turn would launch another activity that would display select fields from that table that the user could then edit.  All of the examples and tutorials I am seeing online typically are starting the listviews from the field level (already having a table selected and being queried).  Is anyone aware of any examples of a top level listview populating the tables within the database?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, why don't you try:

SELECT name FROM DB_NAME
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name;

and use the results to fill an adapter.